# C++ Preprocessor for Debug Statements

Tags: c++, boost-fiber

I have been going through some Boost-Fiber examples and the Boost-Fiber priority scheduler provided by Nat Goodspeed. In his code, he uses the character sequence //<- on the line before debugging code, and //-> on the line following.

I am wondering if there is some sort of C++ preprocessor that either removes this code, or leaves it in depending on the debugging mode.

I would like to use his scheduler, without the debug code, but I didn't want to remove it by hand if something already exists.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you do a global search and replace with  //<-  becoming #ifdef DEBUG and  //-> becoming #endif

Comment: I don't know of a tool, but for anyone interested in seeing an example... https://github.com/boostorg/fiber/blob/develop/examples/priority.cpp

Comment: I wonder if Goodspeed has their own code generator/pre-preprocessor.

Comment: I am sure one could do a search and replace, but I bet that there is some tool.  It could be Goodspeed's own preprocessor.  I just thought there might be something out there that everyone but me was familiar with...